# How to use 30 AMP wire to make 120 outlet

Tags: receptacle

He we had a hot water heater that is on 2 25 amp breakers. We took out the water heater and use a boiler with boiler mate for hot water. The wire that use to go to the the hot water heater is capped off in a junction box. We just added a water softer that runs on a regular  120 outlet. Currently the water softener cord is plugged into the same one as my washer. This is an outlet I often use to run the dehumidifier. I would love to find a way to use the capped off 30 amp wire to make an outlet for the water softer. Is it possible to take the 30 amp wire and convert it to a 120 outlet. I have done very basic wiring of outlet and lights but this is over my head. Money is too tight right now to pay for adding a new outlet so if this can't be converted the plug will stay were it is. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: This is very confusing.  When you say "two 15A breakers" is that the same thing as the "capped off 30A wire" you mention?  Did you decide on your own to call it 30 because of 15+15?  (it doesn't work that way; it's still 15A but voltage doubles to 240V).  Or are these actually two 15A breakers *wired in parallel* serving a 30A load?   Cut up Post-it notes to make flags, then stick them on your breakers and shoot us a pic of the panel. You can [edit] your question to add info.

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion. I just looked at the breaker box again and the 2 breakers that tie into the hot water wire both say 25 amp. The junction box that the wire is capped of has a single wire bundle. The wire use to be hot wired to the water heater it did not have an outlet. I am sorry if this is confusing but I know just enough to get my self in trouble with wiring.

Comment: @harper the op said water heater 240v most water heaters are 30a 240v being fed with 10 awg wire.

Comment: There is no shame in knowing your limits.  If you feel this is over your head, get a qualified professional to take on the risk. This advice applies globally.

Answer (score 4):

yes You can turn this into a 15 or 20 amp receptacle possibly even 2 circuits depending on how many wires in the cable. 
If there is Black, white and a ground you will need to move the wires around in the panel but a legal 15 or 20 amp 120v circuit can be set up.

If this is a main panel 
Put the white on the neutral bus or the ground bus (if white and bare copper are on the same bus(es) either one, of your white wire is too short a splice of white wire long enough to reach the bus is ok. I don’t like changing wire size but if you use the 15 amp breaker you have 14 awg white is ok, if you go for a 20 amp breaker, 12 awg white will be needed.

Next you will need a receptacle, I prefer spec grade back and side they cost a bit more but as most 15 amp receptacles the number 10 wire should fit under the screws.

Wire the white to the silver screw, the black to the brass colored screw and the bare copper to the green screw.

If your cable happens to have 4 wires you could create a multi wire branch circuit (2 circuits) but most water heaters are wired with 3 wires.

Using larger wire is ok and in this case it should fit a receptacle (30 amp wire is normally 10 awg) but could be larger and in that case you would need to pigtail to smaller wire at the receptacle and possibly the breaker.

Update: the op said 25 amp breaker in comment while I was typing the breaker would need to be down sized to feed a standard receptacle. The max breaker is 20 amp and would require a 15 amp duplex receptacle. And 12 awg pig tail if needed.